# File ended while scanning use of \frac with no blank lines

Tags: equations, formatting

Here is my code segment that creates the problem:

```
\begin{equation*}
Pressure Ratio = \frac{p_{03}}{p_{01}},  Mass Flow Rate = \frac{\dot m \sqrt{R T_{01}}{p_{01} d^2}, Specific Heat Capacity = \frac{C_p}{R}, True Air Velocity = \frac{Nd}{\sqrt{R T_{01}},  Reynolds Number = \frac{\dot m}{d \mu_0}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: You missed the closing brace for numerator of the second fraction.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You have missed a `}` of the `\frac` denominator in the second equation and another one in the fourth equation. I have fixed them but they are too long to all fit on the same page. So I used `align` environment to space them and align them. A tip, you should write/align/separate your code the way how I did it, it would be much easier to debug and fix.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    Pressure Ratio          = \frac{p_{03}}{p_{01}},
    Mass Flow Rate          = \frac{\dot m \sqrt{R T_{01}}}{p_{01} d^2},
    Specific Heat Capacity  = \frac{C_p}{R},
    True Air Velocity       = \frac{Nd}{\sqrt{R T_{01}}},  
    Reynolds Number         = \frac{\dot m}{d \mu_0},
\end{equation*}
\\[2ex]
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \text{Pressure Ratio}           &= \frac{p_{03}}{p_{01}}\\
        \text{Mass Flow Rate}           &= \frac{\dot m \sqrt{R T_{01}}}{p_{01} d^2}\\
        \text{Specific Heat Capacity}   &= \frac{C_p}{R}\\
        \text{True Air Velocity}        &= \frac{Nd}{\sqrt{R T_{01}}}\\
        \text{Reynolds Number}          &= \frac{\dot m}{d \mu_0}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `\text{}`, eg, `\text{Pressure Ratio}`.

Comment: @Sigur forgot about that, thanks!